# Hibernate - Ehcache configuration not working (does no hit the second level cache)

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

I have newly configured ehcache for a java application.

This are my pom dependencies

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

These are the new configuration I added for the persistence.xml

```
 <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
```

This is the entity class with caching enabled.

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Table(name = "LABEL")
public class Label implements Serializable{

    @EmbeddedId
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private LabelKey labelKey;
```

When I send the same request to this application multiple times I can see the sql select statement in the logs (I have enables show_sql =true). I assume that this means it's not hitting the second level cache.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you looking up entities? Second level cache only works by id. For queries, you need the query cache: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching-config-properties

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this dependency as well

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.11</version>
</dependency>
```

And when calling createQuery method I had to also call setCachable(true) method